# Unable to reinstall macOS on MacBook Pro after installing Ubuntu

Tags: macos, startup, unix, big-sur

**In the process of installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my Mac Book Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), I formatted the whole disk and installed Ubuntu 20.04. Now I am unable to install macOS back, previously running latest macOS Big Sur**

Things I have tried:

1. **Internet Recovery** over WiFi network by holding Command-R not working, showing error with code -2002f. The same happened when I connect it with my mobile hotsport network.
2. **Connected Ethernet cable** to run Internet Recovery over wired internet, but the wired network isn't showing on the networks available to choose for Internet Recovery.
3. **Not showing bootable USB drive on Startup:** Created a bootable macOS installer with *OS X El Capitan* image and made a bootable USB drive using TransMac on a Windows system. But the drive isn't showing on Startup by holding Option (⌥) after holding immediately after pressing the power button, it is showing only one main drive and not the USB drive!

My findings:

1. I believe the Ubuntu system isn't accessing USB drive ports while startup, as both Ethernet cable (which I connect with TP-Link Ethernet Network Adapter to USB) and the bootable USB drive aren't working
2. All the ports are working fine, as I can able to access internet over Ethernet as well as the USB drive is also working fine.

*Can anyone offer a solution? Please*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. How far do you get when pressing Command-R? Does your Mac successfully start up from the macOS Recovery System (that's the macOS Utilities window with several options like Disk Utility or Reinstall macOS)? If that's not the case, could you try Option-Command-R? This option uses macOS Recovery over the internet. and will hopefully work if you connect your Mac to the internet over Ethernet.

Comment: Hi @jaume, I've tried Option-Command-R, with connected to the Ethernet, still got the same -2002f error! I believe Internet Recovery is running on WiFi and not by Ethernet, as at first it asks to "Select Network" and in the list there are only find WiFi networks and not the Ethernet connection, so I choose a WiFi network from one of them but not an Ethernet connection.

Comment: That's too bad. Your best chance is to use a bootable USB drive. Can you check this blog post https://www.uubyte.com/create-macos-catalina-bootable-usb-on-windows-10.html? It describes three ways to create a bootable USB drive on Windows 10, I hope one of them works.

Comment: thanks for the post, I actually tried one of it: TransMac on Windows. Unfortunately, the machine isn't showing the USB drive on Startup by holding Option (⌥), it's only showing my main hard-drive, not the USB drive!

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, I thought you may want to give the other two methods a try and report back.